# Problema no resultado da multiplicação de matrizes com Multithread em C

Tags: c, c++, matriz, thread, multithreading

Fiz o código abaixo para fazer uma multiplicação de matrizes com multithreads, porém por algum motivo que não consigo identificar, ela não ordena as informações para montar a tabela final.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

int a[3][3] = { 2, 2, 3,
                1, 2, 3,
                1, 2, 3};
int b[3][3] = { 1, 2, 3,
                1, 2, 3,
                1, 2, 3};
int c[3][3];
pthread_t t[3][3];
struct inputs{
 int a;
 int b;
};

void* matricialMulti(void* vargp)
{
    inputs input = *(inputs*)vargp;

    c[input.a][input.b] += a[input.a][input.b] * b[input.b][input.a];
    cout << input.a << " aaa " << input.b << endl;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Inicio das Threads...\n");

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            inputs input;

            input.a = i;
            input.b = j;
            pthread_t thread1;
            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, matricialMulti, (void *)&input);
        }
    }

    /*for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
             pthread_join(t[i][j], NULL);
        }
    }*/

    printf("resultado da tabela 3\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%i\t  ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Esse é o resultado esperado:

```
2         2       3
2         4       6
3         6       9
```

Porém esse é o que está vindo:

```
0         0       3
2         0       6
0         6       45
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando eu vi a pergunta, a primeira coisa que assumo, que é que o `inputs input` está "sendo otimizado". Isso é, não existem 9 `input`, o que existe é apenas um único. Ou seja, quando você faz:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            inputs input;

            input.a = i;
            input.b = j;
            pthread_t thread1;
            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, matricialMulti, (void *)&input);
        }
    }
```

Aparentemente isso é o mesmo que fazer:

```
     inputs input;

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            input.a = i;
            input.b = j;
            pthread_t thread1;
            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, matricialMulti, (void *)&input);
        }
    }
```

Acredito que assim consiga perceber o problema, você está sempre alterando o mesmo local.

---

Uma forma de corrigir isso é alocar dinamicamente, por exemplo:

Eu acho que o problema é que, o `inputs input` é uma variável local, e como está sendo criada dentro de um loop, ela poderia ser trocada para:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            inputs* input = (inputs*)(malloc(sizeof(input)));

            input->a = i;
            input->b = j;
            pthread_t thread1;
            pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, matricialMulti, (void *)input);
        }
    }
```

Dessa forma, a cada loop você terá um novo `inputs`, ao invés de alterar o mesmo struct a cada iteração.

*Note que, você deve alterar o `pthread_create` para incluir um `free`, caso contrário existe um vazamento de recursos.*

---

Além disso, você não está aguardando a conclusão das threads, aparentemente isso pode ser feito usando o trecho de código que comentou:

```
pthread_create(&t[i][j], NULL, matricialMulti, (void *)&input);
```

Depois:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
             pthread_join(t[i][j], NULL);
        }
    }
```

---

**Mas, não sei se este é exatamente o problema.**